# Android WebView in a toast

Tags: android, webview, toast

I am trying to put a WebView into a toast or the Webview to be shown on a small part of the screen.

Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".Webview" />
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webviewEquationsView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the part of the java where I would like to place the webview, code obrained from the android website-toast section:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();     
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_equation_menu,(ViewGroup)     findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I used         WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewEquationsView);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/dsfsdf.....html"); In the other Classes to import the webview

Comment: What is the problem... Where have you set url for the webview.

Comment: Also I have no idea why a troll voted me down, since I spend ages trying to find something that works and I also provided some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();     
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_equation_menu,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
```

Get the WebView from the inflatter view

First add url to the WebView

```
   WebView webview = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webviewEquationsView);   webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
```

Comment: I have found a different solution

Comment: I have used the DIALOG feature where webviews can be placed

Comment: @Gabi apologies for the late reply...You can use Toast also...As you've already done it with the dialog than I'll suggest you to proceed..

Comment: Don't worry, i replied a bit late too. The dialog works very well